# MongoServerError: Direct writes against config.transactions cannot be performed using a transaction or on a session

Tags: mongodb, bash, mongo-shell, drop-database

I try to delete mongodb database using bash script

I got a mistake : MongoServerError: Direct writes against config.transactions cannot be performed using a transaction or on a session.
But I excluded config from all databases. If somebody has any idea, please help Thanks

DATABASES=$(mongosh --host ${DB_HOST} --port ${DB_PORT} --quiet --eval 'show dbs' | awk '!/(admin|config|local)$/{print $1}' | tail -n +3)

for database in ${DATABASES}; do
if [ "${database}" != "admin" ]; then
mongosh --host ${DB_HOST} --port ${DB_PORT} --eval "db.getSiblingDB('${database}').dropDatabase()"
fi
done